# WP7 alternative to tabs

Tags: windows-phone-7, ui-design

I have a mobile app. On the two major smartphone platforms, I employ tabbed UI - there are 3-4 screens with pretty much independent functionality, they exchange info very occasionally, most of the time screen switching is performed by the user, in arbitrary order.

Windows Phone 7 does not have a tab control, and page navigation assumes a stack model (you go back to where you came from). What would be a sensible WP7 alternative to that kind of UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general Phone-7 replacement for the tab paradigm would be either a [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941098%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) or a [Panorama](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941104%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).  Which you choose depends a lot on exactly on what you're showing, but generally speaking the Pivot is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend a [pivot control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941098%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

WP7 UI is built around the metro style and it was a deliberate choice to not have a tab control. (have a look at the official guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) I would recommend you use a metro control like panorama or pivot.